# Rails as_json, adding a custom attribute without a serializer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rendering, overriding

I have a rails application which needs to output a custom json response.

I have a `Post` model which has many `statuses`. The `status` of a `post` is different for every `user`.

I want to return `Post.all` as json with every `post` containing the user-dependent `status`es as regular attributes (attributes which seem like they belong to `post`, nothing nested)

How would I do this? I do not want to pass the current_user method to my model and I also do not want to use a serializer.

Is there anyway I could do something like this:

```
respond_with(posts: @posts.as_json(:methods => [:status(current_user)])
#NOTE the current user arg
```

### EDIT:

clarification, I want:

```
id: 1, content: 'this is a post', status: 'reviewed'
#as json of course
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could I do this: `@posts= Post.all(include: :statuses, conditions: { statuses: {user_id: current_user.id}})`?

Comment: the above comment would be nested, i prefer something not nested. The above does not show all posts each with a status record though. Instead it returns every post which has a status record from the current user

Comment: Perhaps write a `status_for_current_user` method on `Post`?

Comment: Something like `return statuses.where(:user_id => current_user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following to my PostsController:

```
def json_params_for(objects)
   collection = objects.map do |post|
   { id: post.id,
     content: post.content,
     created_at: post.created_at,
     status: "reviewed
    }
   end
   collection.to_json
end
```

all json customized within my controller where I can access `current_user`